# XGBoost custom objective causing "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"

Tags: r, xgboost

I have searched for a solution to this problem, but everything I've found leads me to believe that this is a problem with either my OS or my RStudio/R version. I am trying to create a custom objective function for XGBoost. However, it looks like one set of parameters works, while the other doesn't:

```
require(xgboost)

data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(agaricus.train$data, label = agaricus.train$label)
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(agaricus.test$data, label = agaricus.test$label)

watchlist <- list(eval = dtest, train = dtrain)
num_round <- 2

huberobj <- function(preds, dtrain) {
  d <- getinfo(dtrain, "label") - preds
  h <- 1
  scale <- 1+(d/h)^2
  scale_sqrt <- scale^(1/2)
  grad <- d/scale_sqrt
  hess <- 1/scale/scale_sqrt
  return(list(grad = grad, hess = hess))
}

evalerror <- function(preds, dtrain) {
  d <- getinfo(dtrain, "label") - preds
  h <- 1 
  scale <- 1 + (d / h)^2
  err <- sum(sqrt(scale))
  return(list(metric = "error", value = err))
}

xgbParam <- list( max_depth=2    
                , eta=1 
                , nthread = 2
                , silent = 1
                , objectve=huberobj
                , eval_metric=evalerror
)

param <- list( max_depth=2
             , eta=1
             , nthread = 2
             , silent=1
             , objective=huberobj
             , eval_metric=evalerror
             )

bst <- xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round, watchlist)
bst <- xgb.train(xgbParam, dtrain, num_round, watchlist)
```

The model trained on param will work, but the one trained on xgbParam throws the following error:

```
Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

I chased the error to the following function in XGBoost:

```
`xgb.parameters<-` <- function(object = handle, value = NULL) {
  if (length(value) == 0) return(object)
  p <- as.list(value)
  if (is.null(names(p)) || any(nchar(names(p)) == 0)) {
    stop("parameter names cannot be empty strings")
  }
  names(p) <- gsub("\\.", "_", names(p))
  p <- lapply(p, function(x) as.character(x)[1])
  handle <- xgb.get.handle(object)
  for (i in seq_along(p)) {
    .Call(XGBoosterSetParam_R, handle, names(p[i]), p[[i]])
  }
  if (is(object, 'xgb.Booster') && !is.null(object$raw)) {
    object$raw <- xgb.save.raw(object$handle)
  }
  object
}
```

However when I manually go through this function, I do not get an error. Is anyone else getting the same error? If not, does anyone know what may cause it? Any insight into this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The problem lies in the xgbParam definition. You misspelled objective. Fix this and it works the same as param.